# OSGI - Choose which bundle to activate from another Component class

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I want to develop OSGI storage service so I created an interface called `Store`. Now, I have two classes that implement this interface.

SqlStorage.java

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
public class SqlStorage implements Store {
    //some code here
}
```

MongoStorage.java

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
public class MongoStorage implements Store {
    //some code here
}
```

Now, I have another bundle that depends on the `Store`.

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
public class StoreManager implements StoreService {
    // how can I select one of the implmentation here
    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY)
    public Store store;
}
```

How can the `StoreManager` choose which implementation of `Store` to be used?

Suppose, `StoreManager` has the ability to choose whether to use SQL or MongoDB as a storage.

Is this kind of scenario doable?

Answer (score 1):

How does your store manager *want* to decide which implementation of Store to use? As you have currently defined them, the Store implementations are equivalent and equally good answers, and so OSGi will choose one arbitrarily.

If that's not what you want then you need to add service properties to distinguish the Stores. For example:

```
@Component(property = { "region=NorthAmerica", "language=en_US" })
@Component(property = { "region=Europe", "language=en_GB" })
@Component(property = { "region=Asia", "language=jp" })
```

Then your store manager can select the store it wants using a target filter. For example if it wants an English-language store (but doesn't care about American vs British English) then it can use the following filter:

```
@Reference(target = "(language=en*)")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I want the `StoreManager ` to have the ability to choose the `Store`. Now, Is this key value property redefinable? I want to use a proper name instead of `region` and `language` as in your example.

Comment: Also, I wonder if I can achieve this kind of scenario dynamically through CLI or GUI. Instead of hard-coded in the `@Component` and `@Reference`

Comment: You can use any names you like. "region" and "language" are just examples I pulled out of thin air.

Comment: If you want programmatic rather than declarative control over the target service selection, then you need to use a reference with Multiple cardinality to get visibility of all the services. Then you can look at the properties of the services and select over them however you like.